# Install4j with javaagents?

Tags: install4j, javaagents

We tried to use -javaagent with an install4j bundled application. This doesn't work because the statement of the -javaagent has to be first in the parameter list.
But install4j sets its own parameters at the first position and I don't know how to get a -javaagent parameter to the first position. I activate the install4j log and see that other parameters are always the first.

Another possibility would be to use a JDK to start the install4j bundled application, but you can only use JREs an no JDKs. With a JDK you could register JavaAgents dynamically via the Java class VirtualMachine.

Answer (score 0):

The `-javaagent` does not have to be the first argument, but it has to be a VM parameter and not an argument to the main class. Arguments to an executable created by install4j are passed to the main class, unless they are prefixed with `-J` in which case they are passed as VM parameters.

So you pass

```
-J-javaagent:...
```

on the command line, it will be passed properly.

See [install4j manual](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/concepts/vmParameters.html), scroll to "Passing VM parameters on the command line".

Comment: I took the liberty to add a link to your answer.